# Directive loaded from ng-bind-html doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Inside the controller:

```
$scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml('<some-directive></some-directive>');
```

The template:

```
<!-- Works perfectly -->
<some-directive></some-directive>

<!-- HTML loaded correctly, but the directive inside won't execute -->
<div class="article__main" ng-bind-html="content"></div>
```

**What is going on here, exactly? How do I tell angular to check the DOM for new directives that are going to be added via ng-bind-html?** BTW, I'm testing now and the directive is just logging to console, nothing else.

I used ng-include + a file on another version of the website (instead on ng-bind-html) and that worked.

Thanks on advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the $compile Service.

```
var compiledTemplate = $compile(content)(scope);
```

You also have to define the parent scope.[Here is the Doku to $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

I never used it with `ng-bind-html` but setting it on the DOM with `element.append()` works just fine